# How to identify the elements that do not match a given sequence in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, search

Consider the given sequence `sequence = [1, 1, 0]`.

An example of an array that follows the sequence throughout is `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`.

I have an array that follows the sequence throughout except with a few outliers. An example of such an array is `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]`. In this array, the elements that are outliers are at the 6th and 16th indices. If these outliers are removed, the array would follow the sequence throughout.

I want to write a python code that prints the indices of the outliers in the array. The array is assumed to have only 0s and 1s.

The code should look like below:

```
sequence = [1, 1, 0]
array_with_outliers = [...] //given
//code to identify outliers
print(indices_of_outliers)
```

### My Failed Attempts

I tried to break the array_with_outliers into chunks of 3 elements. I then iterated through the chunks to see if they matched the sequence. If chunk n didn't match the sequence, I popped the elements upto index 3(n-1) in the array_with_outliers and chunked the array_with_outliers again, carrying out the same process recursively till the array_with_outliers was empty. The code was too inefficient, however, and my laptop wasn't able to run it.

I also tried to iterate the array_with_outliers and see if each element matched its expected value based on the sequence. I computed the expected value based on the index and the number of outliers identified so far. However, the problem was that I was individually comparing each element to its expected value, and not the chunk as a whole, which created overlapping problems.

Comment: What "overlapping problems"?

Comment: Is the sequence always [1, 1, 0] or at least always has length 3?

Comment: Consider the array `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]`. When iterating through the array, at the 3rd index, the expected value is 1, so my code marks the 3rd index to not be an outlier. However, if we see the entire chunk `[1, 1, 1]`, we realise the 3rd index is an outlier.

Comment: It's always `[1, 1, 0]`

Comment: Ok, if that's how it's supposed to work, then Samwise's answer seems right, after all. Why did you unaccept it?

Comment: I was just testing a few different cases. I reaccepted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in linear time by just iterating through the array, skipping matching chunks, and accumulating non-matching indices one at a time until you find the next matching chunk.

```
def find_outliers(needle: list[int], haystack: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Find indices in haystack where
    the sequence of repeated needles is broken."""
    outliers: list[int] = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(haystack):
        if haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle:
            i += len(needle)
        else:
            outliers.append(i)
            i += 1
    return outliers

assert not find_outliers(
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
)

assert find_outliers(
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
) == [6, 16]
```

Comment: the outliners definition would not give you an unique answer. example: [1, 1, 1, 0] with [1, 1, 0] sequence what would be the answer [0]? [1]? or perhaps [2]

Comment: Maybe it becomes more clear if one thinks of outliers as leaving a hole in the array when removed. So in [1, 1, 1, 0], if the 0th index is removed, it becomes [hole, 1, 1, 0], which keeps the sequence [1, 1, 0] intact. But if we remove an element at any other index, the hole prevents the sequence from forming. For example [1, hole, 1, 0]. I should have obviously made this clearer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bytes.find` to find the occurrences of the sequence. My `i` tells where the next occurrence is *expected* to start and `j` tells where it *actually* starts. (Framework mostly copied from Samwise.)

```py
def find_outliers(needle: list[int], haystack: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    """Find indices in haystack where
    the sequence of repeated needles is broken."""
    outliers: list[int] = []
    i = 0
    needle = bytes(needle)
    find = bytes(haystack).find
    while (j := find(needle, i)) != -1:
        outliers += range(i, j)
        i = j + len(needle)
    outliers += range(i, len(haystack))
    return outliers

assert not find_outliers(
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
)

assert find_outliers(
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
) == [6, 16]

assert find_outliers(
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
) == [3, 4]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVJBbsIwEJR6zCumnLAwCNQKVUjpsZ9AVhXIpnGIHGo7QrylFy6t-qa-po5D3IRyIkqcXe_M7Kzsj6_90eaVOp0-a5tNn37uvlPKkEmVvla1LSVpM1ZEaUkrlNLYtVRWcOTJ0dhku-ttMkyf_7JVBPeMRqMXJwX3yS0Z9w9MHHLS5FE2Jxh6r0ltCVUGTXtKLKVoGzuawUZXO1IzJ-gpnbdef8RYC1-ULpz7qBVw6eZoqRuE-VIzYih0ptis2fb1Qy4dc1xgFXvsmcwhGcN9jOmiHbHvBpMYOlFvNJYcBQv1xlCBCUpSAw9XeQ0o-GlxmmytVYBHUWIMaQtV2Yuj8vD1gsO9c8EHqV8HgYhY0LpJ54rmv-DcCLE7n6VLl-Lmnp3MA8ejaC_s-d529_cX)

Answer (score 1):

you can take advantage of `bytearray` and its built-in methods if you want to code less like:

```
sample = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

def seq_finder(sample, sequence):
    seq = bytearray(sequence)
    sam = bytearray(sample).replace(seq, b"-"*len(seq))
    res = []
    for i in range(len(sam)):
        if sam[i] != 45:
            res.append(i)
    return res


print(seq_finder(sample, [1, 1, 0])) #[6, 16]
```

Comment: You're not mutating the bytearray, so you can just use bytes instead. [Variation](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVBBCsIwEMRrL35h6amRVNSTiL6kFEnbDQbaNKYJ2Ld46UUf5WtMGqseNIQwu7Ozu5nrXfXm1MphuFnD0-1jNu9Yo2qEA2RrCu6uxjeAb_wPeJxHUYUcOjwfuZAV6iR0pT5lUZZIdhG440I3qegNdsmbCgxrPswoJkuNqmYl-koKRZzGixqlj0jQaDRWS8gE8FaDoHABIQGlbVAzg74PAcFdeg8bt6PSQprkx5bT13NCgi8veyabng) with nicer collection.